# Google Analytics dimension1 is undefined gtag

Tags: google-analytics, analytics-events, custom-dimensions

I have recently set up Google Analytics on my site with `gtag`. I have created 1 dimension, `store_name`. I have added the code to send the dimension value right after the function call like so:

```
gtag('config', 'UA-1111111111-1', {
    'custom_map': {'dimension1': 'store_name'}
});
gtag('event', 'store_name_dimension', {'store_name': 'name1'});
```

Using the chrome extension, i see that `dimension1` is set to `undefines`.

```
ga("gtag_UA_111111111_1.send", "pageview", {forceSSL: true, &gtm: "u5o", hitCallback: [function], dimension1: undefined})
```

But a little lower down i see that the dimension is being called correct.

```
ga("gtag_UA_11111111_1.send", "event", {dimension1: "name1", forceSSL: true, &gtm: "u5o", hitCallback: [function], eventCategory: "general", eventAction: "store_name_dimension"})
```

How can i validate that it is sending the dimension value to the admin panel? Is this the correct way to send the dimension? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is fine. You end up having your custom dimension associated with that session thanks to your event hit. You are not sending dimension value on your pageview.